# Passing values from a php generated table to modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I got a table generated in PHP:

```
<tbody>
<?php
    $results = DB::select()->from('users')->execute();
    foreach ($results as $user) {
        echo "<tr id='".$user['id']."'>
        <input type=\"hidden\" id='userNameHidden' value='".$user['username']."'>
        <input type=\"hidden\" id='userEmailHidden' value='".$user['email']."'>
        <td class='username'>".$user['username']."</td><td class='email'>".$user['email']."</td><td class='lastlogin'>".date('d/m/Y',$user['last_login'])."</td><td class='logins'>".$user['logins']."</td><td><a class='editThis'><i class=\"small material-icons\">mode_edit</i></a> <a href='#deleteUser' class='deleteThis'><i class=\"small material-icons\">delete</i></a> </td></tr>";

    }
?>
```

My question is, how to make the edit/delete buttons work on a modal that is opened on the same site? I just want to pass values from `<td>` to `<input type="text">` on the modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it with `GET` or `POST` method to another php file and than work with them there. If you want to work on the same page you can get it via JavaScript:

```
var value = document.getElementById ( "userNameHidden" ).innerText;
```

After that:

```
document.getElementById ( "inputid" ).value = value;
```

If you would like to create a login system definately use POST or GET (not recommended) to pass the values.

If you want it to happen with a button click. You can make a funcion and a button to go with it:

```
<button onclick="delete()">Delete</button>
```

And the js:

```
function delete(){
var value = document.getElementById ( "userNameHidden" ).innerText;
document.getElementById ( "inputid" ).value = value;
}
```